# Share plugin won't open separate window for app in Capacitor JS

Tags: javascript, android, ionic-framework, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I want to share some info and url within another app (WhatsApp or Telegram for example) and that app opened over my app, in the same window. How to open it in new window, like target _blank?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want the application to which I share information - open not on top of my application, but separately.